# add new column using SQLite

Tags: sqlite, r

I am trying to insert a new column in a R dataframe using `sqldf`, using the example 4 from [sqldf](http://code.google.com/p/sqldf/)

```
abbr <- data.frame (species = levels(iris[,"Species"]),
                    abbr = c("s","ve","vi"))
sqldf("select abbr, avg(Sepal_Length) from iris natural join abbr group by species")

sqldf("select abbr, avg(Sepal_Length) from iris join abbr using(Species) group by Species")
```

Both sqldf command works, but it fails when I change the column name of abbr from `abbr` to `abbr_col`, I don't know which `abbr` in the sql syntax should be changed.

Thanks.

#### update #01

```
> abbr <- data.frame (species = levels(iris[,"Species"]),
+                     abbr_col = c("s","ve","vi"))
> sqldf("select abbr_col, avg(Sepal_Length) from iris natural join abbr_col group by species")
Error in sqliteExecStatement(con, statement, bind.data) : 
  RS-DBI driver: (error in statement: no such table: abbr_col)
```

I tried renaming all `abbr` into `abbr_col`, but fail.

Comment: It's not clear what you want to do.

Comment: I modified the question with additional background info, thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One “abbr” is table name, another one is column name:

```
abbr_table <- data.frame (species = levels(iris[,"Species"]),
                          abbr_col = c("s","ve","vi"))
sqldf("select abbr_col, avg(Sepal_Length) from iris natural join abbr_table group by species")
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to rename column from `abbr` to `abbr_col`, then you need change *all* of the `abbr` occurrences to `abbr_col`.